# SQL or Spring JDBC return object of objects

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-jdbc

Is it possible for postgres-sql or Spring JDBC to return data with the following shape:

```
    {
      id: 1
      profit: 200
      sales_rep: {
        name: 'bob',
        age: 9,
        gender: male
    }
```

where name, age, and gender are inside the key 'sales_rep' before it reaches the repository layer? Or do I have to retrieve flat data and then put it into the shape I want in repository layer using java.

Please assume we are using two tables 'earnings' and 'sales_rep' with foreign key being 'sales_rep_id' for the sake of argument.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres SQL, you can do this easily with json functions:

```
select jsonb_build_object(
    'id',        e.id,
    'profit',    e.profit
    'sales_rep', jsonb_build_object(
        'name',   sr.name,
        'age',    sr.age,
        'gender', sr.gender
    )
) js
from earnings e
inner join sales_rep sr on sr.sales_rep_id = e.sales_rep_id
```

This gives you a resultset with one row per `earning` and a single colum, that contains a jsonb payload with the structure that you asked for.